# Assign X-Axis label to Chart Framework

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using the [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) framework. 
I was able to add the data to the chart but I am not able to change the X-axis labels on the chart.

Earlier, it could be done using:

**Variables:**

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

var sales = [230, 220, 240, 170, 90, 60, 150, 140, 160, 170, 140, 250]
```

**ViewDidLoad:**

```
let salesEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, y: 250)
    let salesEntry2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: 260)
    salesEntries.append(salesEntry1)
    salesEntries.append(salesEntry2)


    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: salesEntries, label: "Sales")

    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChart.data = chartData
```

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Comment: can you update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently as the old initializer is not available

Code:

```
let labels = ["Value 1", "Value 2"]
barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
```

Set the labels for each of the bars

Set **granularity** of X-Axis to 1

```
 barChart.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

> **Note:** This is a Swift 3 issue for Charts (v3.0.1)

Refer gitHub issues [Charts/Issues/1800](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1800)